# How can I determine whether pipes in my basement are actually drains?

Tags: plumbing

So I've had a plumber friend tell me the best way to see if 3 pipes in my basement are drains is to put a Garden hose in them and run the water.  What if the pipes under the slab are cracked?  Won't water just sit there then under the slab?  Sounds bad

Comment: In my experience it is rare to find pipes that are not connected to a drain field or sewer. I would take your friend's advice.

Answer (score 2):

The ground under your home is loaded with water. It may be down a ways, but it's there. Any water you add will percolate down to the existing water table. The only real concern is temporary flooding. Use common sense. Monitor the entire area while you run your test. Use an assistant if available. Look and listen.